# ¿Como hacer mas eficiente el codigo de python y su lectura de Diccionario en los .txt?

Tags: python-3.x, diccionarios, txt

estaba realizando una practica para aprender sobre como usar los diccionarios en python por medio de inserción de información a través de .txt, el como manejarlo y luego vizualisarlo según sea requerido, pero aun asi siento que de todas las maneras en que lo hice, sigue estando lento, espero recibir su ayuda Gracias a Todos de Antemano.

[image: Aqui esta el .txt de donde se leé la información]

```
dic_datos = {}
file = open('usuarios_paswords.txt', 'r')
username = open('user.txt', 'w')
passwords = open ('password.txt', 'w')
dicc_datos = open('diccionario_datos.txt', 'w')
dicc_datos_acomodados = open ('diccionario_agrupado.txt','w')

for line in file:
    parts = line.split(':')
    dic_datos [parts[0]] = parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]
    name = parts[3]
    password = parts[4]

    username.write(name)
    username.write('\n')
    passwords.write(password)
    passwords.write('\n')
''' Crea un archivó separado por : y de esta forma tener un diccionario '''
for u in dic_datos:
    dicc_datos.write('{0}:{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}'. format(u,str(dic_datos[u][0]),str(dic_datos[u][1]),str(dic_datos[u][2]),str(dic_datos[u][3]),str(dic_datos[u][4])))
    dicc_datos.write('\n')
    
''' Crea un .txt detallado '''
for o in dic_datos:
i_d = o
status = dic_datos[o][0]
country = dic_datos[o][1]
user = dic_datos[o][2]
pass_single = dic_datos[o][3]
timestamp = dic_datos[o][4]
dicc_datos_acomodados.write('''
ID : {}
STATUS : {}
COUNTRY : {}
USER : {}
PASSWORD : {}
TIMESTAMP : {}
'''. format(i_d,status,country,user,pass_single,timestamp))
    dicc_datos.write('\n')
''' muestra el acomodo en la consola '''
for x in dic_datos:
print('''
ID :\t {}
STATUS : {}
COUNTRY : {}
USER :\t {}
PASSWORD: {}
TIMESTAMP {}
'''. format(x,dic_datos[x][0],dic_datos[x][1],dic_datos[x][2],dic_datos[x][3],dic_datos[x][4]))

file.close()
username.close()
passwords.close()
dicc_datos.close()
dicc_datos_acomodados.close()
```

luego de eso lo que se vizualisa es esto:

[image: informacion detallada]

y este el que se usaria para diccionarios si se pide en un nuevo proceso

[image: separado las dos partes por :]

Comment: ¿Dónde estaría la ineficiencia?

Comment: recorres cuatro veces dic_datos, una para crearlo y 3 para manejarlos,yo lo haria todo en paralelo y no crearía dic_datos salvo que quiera controlar repeticiones...

Comment: no asignes tantas variables que luego solo usas para pasarlas al ficheros, pasa directamente el vector parts con su índice correspondiente

Comment: no hagas dos llamadas a write seguidas si puedes hacerlo en una

Comment: declara funciones para no repetir código y clarificarlo(opcional)

Comment: Demasiados errores en el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tener el consejo de ustedes es bueno, y aunque paresca nada agradesco, estoy aprendiendo y muy buenos datos de todo, hice varios llamados para no subir codigo independientes, y gracias a ustedes aprendi bastante.